# Efficient library for building, intersecting and measuring 3D meshes

Tags: python, 3d, geometry, mesh

I'm working with Python 3.10.

Say i have a few set of points in a ring shape, contained in parallel planes.
I would like to :

1. Build a 3D mesh by linking the rings with triangles

[image: like this]

2. Intersect this 3D mesh with another one, for instance a cylinder or sphere
3. Measure some metrics on this mesh (volume, area, height, etc...)

I am already confident i could figure a way to do this "from scratch", however, i don't have much time (I'm experimenting different ideas here) and i would like to get some performance out of it to be able to see how it fares with use in an optimization algorithm.

Does anyone know a python library that can do at least some of the steps. i already found some, like [PyMesh](https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but (maybe I'm wrong) but it does seem it does only the "intersection part" of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these libraries: `PyMesh`, `Trimesh` or `Open3D`. Refers to the docs to use them.